# set scroll last UItableview cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

when I scroll position end of UItableview the last UItableview row seems half. how can I show the last row fully and how can I detect scroll to last row?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "seems half". I suppose that means only half of the cell is shown? Make sure the frame of the whole table view is visible first.

If you want a cell to appear within the bounds of the table view, use

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:? section:?]
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: Implement `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in your delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something (like a tabBar) at the bottom of your screen and it is overlapping the UITableView .. am I right, am I right?!

Just make the frame of the UITableView 48 pixels shorter. That's the average size of a tabBar..

Or perhaps you have not taken in account that the bar at the top (the status bar) also counts, which is about 15 pixels high. In that case, take 15 pixels of the height of your UITableView's frame.

Comment: I did like [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)]; in IUTableController but it doesn't change.